# Функции без круглых скобок С++

Tags: c++, функции

Почему в данном коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool wayToSort(int i, int j) { return i > j; }

int main()
{
    vector<int> intVec = {56, 32, -43, 23, 12, 93, 132, -154};

    sort(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), wayToSort);

    for (int i : intVec)
        cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

в sort() после функции wayToSort не стоят круглые скобки?

Comment: Потому, что в последнем аргументе `sort` передаётся ссылка на функцию, а не результат её вызова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), wayToSort);
```

Это означает: отсортировать вектор `intVec`, используя для сравнения элементов функцию `wayToSort`. То есть, функция `sort` получает адрес функции `wayToSort` как параметр, и затем вызывает `wayToSort` для сравнения элементов. На профессинальном языке `wayToSort` это callback address.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы здесь не вызываете `wayToSort`. Вы передаете ее в `sort()`, которая сама вызывает ее для нужных пар элементов (т.е. круглые скобочки, которые вы ищите - они внутри `sort`).